# How does the packet find the shortest path in a computer network?

Tags: networking, shortest-path

Does it use some kind of Djikstra? Then what are the weights?
I was reading about computer networks..And thought about it
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Routing algorithms are used by individual routers to determine the direction in which packets are sent. They can be simple, like RIP, that looks at advertised path costs received from other routers, or more complex, like OSPF, in which a model of the network is built within each router and a Djikstra is run to determine the best path.  The trade off between them is the complexity of management and the resource consumption on each router.

Software Defined Networks are exploring options where a central controller makes all of the forwarding decisions and distributes them to the network elements that are handling the traffic.  Technologies like OpenFlow are in use in large production networks today.